# What is the different between pacman -Syu, -Syyu and -Syuu?

Tags: arch-linux

What is the different between pacman -Syu, -Syyu and -Syuu?

Some will say `pacman -Syyu` or `pacman -Syy` to update archlinux rather than `-Syu` ([1](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/141712466))

and `-Syuu` after changing repositories ([2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Official_repositories#Disabling_testing_repositories))

I want to know the meaning of the double `y` and double `u`

and which is better, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [`man pacman`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pacman.8), bold formatting added:

> **-u, --sysupgrade**
> Upgrades all packages that are out-of-date. Each currently-installed
> package will be examined and upgraded if a newer package exists. A
> report of all packages to upgrade will be presented, and the operation
> will not proceed without user confirmation. Dependencies are
> automatically resolved at this level and will be installed/upgraded if
> necessary.
>
> **Pass this option twice to enable package downgrades**; in this case,
> pacman will select sync packages whose versions do not match with the
> local versions. This can be useful when the user switches from a
> testing repository to a stable one.
>
> Additional targets can also be specified manually, so that `-Su foo`
> will do a system upgrade and install/upgrade the "`foo`" package in
> the same operation.
>
> **-y, --refresh**
>
> Download a fresh copy of the master package database from the
> server(s) defined in [`pacman.conf(5)`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pacman.conf.5.en). This should typically be
> used each time you use `--sysupgrade` or `-u`. **Passing two `--refresh`
> or `-y` flags will force a refresh of all package databases**, even if
> they appear to be up-to-date.

The wiki recommends `-Syuu` when disabling the test repo as you *may* need to downgrade some packages.

The generally recommended option is to use `-Syu`. In particular, if using `-Sy`, `-Su` should be done either with it (so `-Syu`) or soon after (see [the System Maintenance FAQ](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported)).

As for `-yy`, it is generally ***not recommended***. Use it only if you're having problems with your mirror. Unless your mirror is acting up and you want to switch mirrors, there is no reason to re-download every package DB file in its entirety every time you want to do an upgrade. You might want to use it when switching mirrors so that all your package DB files are consistent.